# Windows memory leak detection to overcome rapid memory allocation leading to unresponsiveness

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, monitoring, memory-limit, memory-leaks

As a diverse application developer, by sheer "luck" and a combination of Murphy's law, one may hit situations in which either a memory leak occurs or rapid unwanted allocation of memory resources, which one didn't think of before.

At that point, the situation may be worse than a crash, as on the one hand rapid memory allocation leads to unresponsiveness, on the other hand, the almost immediate swapping process fills your harddisk, and thus specific application memory dumps are harder to obtain.

Simply putting more memory into the developer-computer system doesn't help me much either, as with a 1-3GBy/second allocation, and a motherboard that maxes out at 32GB, I would only have a few seconds to notice the situation and react.

In such situations, all I could seem to do is hit the power button.

**Thus the question:**

> *Is there a windows kernel patch/module or monitoring application which immediately suspends an application and pops up a window asking me if I would like to continue the process?*

**Potential workarounds**

Could one limit the memory allocation per process in Windows?

Does setting the process priority to background processes help such situations?

32bit processes should be capped at 4GB. May that be used as a partial solution, or does Win64 somehow overcome this limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: [This SO question and its answers might be worth your attention.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192876/set-windows-process-or-user-memory-limit)